# Which C standard library functions use malloc under the hood

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, x86

I want to know which C standard library functions use `malloc` and `free` under the hood. It looked to me as if `printf` would be using `malloc`, but when I tested a program with `valgrind`, I noticed that `printf` calls didn't allocate any memory using `malloc`. How come? How does it manage the memory then?

Comment: You can read the source code. For instance, get a copy of the glibc source code from git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git

Comment: I took the liberty of reading that myself, and it used a buffer on the stack.

Comment: I was a little too hasty: if strings become too long it starts dynamically allocing using malloc. The code is very hard to read so I will stop saying things about it.

Answer (score 9):

Usually, the only routines in the C99 standard that might use `malloc()` are the standard I/O functions (in `<stdio.h>` where the file structure and the buffer used by it is often allocated as if by `malloc()`.  Some of the locale handling may use dynamic memory. All the other routines have no need for dynamic memory allocation in general.

Now, is any of that formally documented?  No, I don't think it is.  There is no blanket restriction 'the functions in the library shall not use `malloc()`'.  (There are, however, restrictions on other functions - such as `strtok()` and `srand()` and `rand()`; they may not be used by the implementation, and the implementation may not use any of the other functions that may return a pointer to a static memory location.)  However, one of the reasons why the extremely useful `strdup()` function is not in the standard C library is (reportedly) because it does memory allocation.  It also isn't completely clear whether this was a factor in the routines such as `asprintf()` and `vasprintf()` in TR 24731-2 not making it into C1x, but it could have been a factor.

Answer (score 5):

The standard doesn't place any requirements on the implementation, AFAIK.

I don't know exactly how `printf` is implemented, but of the top of my head, I can't think of a reason why it would need to dynamically allocate memory.  You could always look at the source for your platform.

Comment: It's instructive to look ay uses of malloc in http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c -- even with !Omit_Private_Memory some malloc calls remain.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You mean for `fprintf`?  Isn't the buffer managed elsewhere?

Comment: @Doug: That's some of the ugliest code I've ever seen...  (Also, `dtoa` isn't standard C.)

Comment: `printf("%.*g", number, precision")` comes to my mind. Try for instance with `number=1e-300` and `precision=1000`. You surely need to allocate memory dynamically for this.

Comment: I was thinking specifically of functions such as `fgetc()`, but any of the standard I/O functions manipulating the `FILE` behind the `FILE *`.  You can provide a buffer to override the system-provided buffer with the `setbuf()` and `setvbuf()` functions, but most people most of the time do not do so, and the standard I/O library provides a buffer for them from somewhere.  On at least some systems, that buffer is allocated as if by `malloc()`.  (Working from memory without checking today: I believe Solaris was one such system.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That could well be true.

Comment: fopen(  FILE *stream),  
fdopen(int fd, const char *mode), 
and FILE *freopen(const char *pathname, const char *mode, FILE *stream);


 allocations are freed by 

fclose(FILE *stream); 
 
Don't try to free FILE pointers with free() , but do free them with fclose().

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which `libc` you are using. There should be no restriction on the C spec and up to the implementation.

For instance, newlib's `printf` usually done with using memory on stack frame, but when it really needs to, it calls an internal function `_malloc_r()` directly.

I have not used `valgrind`, I'm not sure if it can detect use of `_malloc_r()`.

Comment: "It depends on which `libc` you are using" is the only correct answer.         Newlib actually lists required OS routines on a per-function basis in their official  documentation.  If a function lists sbrk as a required OS function, then it uses some form of malloc.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the C nor the POSIX standard force implementors to make use of `malloc()`, so there's no general answer to your question.

However, every sane standard library implementation that uses `malloc()` in one of its functions will set `errno` to `ENOMEM` if `malloc()` fails. Hence, you can derive from the documentation whether a library function uses `malloc()` or not. Point in case: on my system, `mmap()` may use `malloc()`, since `mmap()` may set `errno` to `ENOMEM`.

That having said, using `valgrind` is a poor way to find out whether a particular function calls `malloc()` or not. Consider the following piece of code:

```
void foo(int x)
{
    if (!x) malloc(1);
}
```

If you call this function with an argument other than `0`, valgrind won't notice that it may actually call `malloc()`. Think of `valgrind` as a virtual machine (since that's what it is): it doesn't look at your code, it only sees what the machine would actually execute.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that the `mmap()` system call makes use of the `malloc()` library function.

Answer (score 1):

printf doesn't need to form the entire output string in one shot, it can send it to output piece by piece, and when it encounters a format specifier, it can output that piece of data as it is formed, and continue on with the rest of the string.

At most it would need a locally defined array of characters (on the stack) large enough to hold the largest integer or floating point number it can handle, which isn't very large.